# Find the mass function of the random variable Y=Max{0,8}

Tags: probability-theory

Problem: Let X be a random variable with geometric distribution and parameter p, $0<p<1$. Find the mass function of the random function variable Y=Max{X,8}.

Attempt:

Y=Max{X,8}$\Rightarrow$$X$, if $x<8$ and $8$, if $x\geq 8$

$g(y)=pq^{y-1}, y=1,2,...$

$g(8)=P(x\geq 8)=\sum_{x=8}^{\infty} pq^{x-1}=q^7$

Is this reasoning correct? Something about my work doesn't seem right. All feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You reasoning is correct. The probabilities of $Y$ add up to $1$ and you have the correct domain for $Y$. So why not?

Comment: Note that $\Pr(X\ge 8)=q^7$  is obvious, since $X\ge 8$ iff the first $7$ results are failures.